# bottomNavigationBar using Scaffold issue: Error Assertion failed: !_needsLayout is not true

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, flutter-web

I just clone project from `Flutter > material > BottomNavigationBar class` example with command `flutter create --sample=material.BottomNavigationBar.2 mysample` (No changes in example code) and run with `flutter run -d chrome`.
But, when I switch widget options many times fastly.
Sometime I get the error like this [Error: Assertion failed: !_needsLayout is not true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm3Ko.png), and my debugging is paused.

Reference Resoures: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: How fast are you switching widget options? Do you have a video or visual representation?

Comment: sorry about this, I just get this error when using physical RAM 8 GB on my pc, and just in debugging. Now, I add up to 16 gb RAM and i will not take this error.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it figured out.